# Browse server on different domain (ckeditor-laravel-elfinder)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, ckeditor

The same problem was addressed [here](http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/CKFinder-another-domain) but it didn't work for me.I am using [laravel-elfinder](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-elfinder) package to integrate the browsing capability to my Laravel 4 app with ckeditor.
My project is running on http://project.com. I keep resources in different domain (say http://resources.project.com).

Whenever I press Browse Server button it browse files from http://project.com/ckfinder/ckfinder.html , I need to browse files from http://resources.project.com.

This is default browsing URL (as in the [documentation](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-elfinder))

```
  filebrowserBrowseUrl: '{{ url('/elfinder/ckeditor4')}}
```

And this is how I set my routes

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function(){
   Route::get('elfinder', 'Barryvdh\Elfinder\ElfinderController@showIndex');
   Route::any('elfinder/connector', 'Barryvdh\Elfinder\ElfinderController@showConnector');

   Route::get('elfinder/ckeditor4', 'Barryvdh\Elfinder\ElfinderController@showCKeditor4');

});
```

It works fine if the files are inside http://project.com but I can't access the files located under http://resources.project.com. Both domains live in the same server.